# xargs exits without waiting for subprocess output

Tags: bash, xargs

My script should exit only after all sub-processes (tasks) are done. I use `xargs` to run tasks in parallel. If a task ends with an error, it should wait for all running tasks to finish, but no new tasks should start. Here I run 3 tasks: `sleep 4`, `sleep 2`, and `sleep 1`. No more than 2 tasks in parallel. The `sleep 1` task crashes, but for some reason xargs does not wait for `sleep 4` to finish, exiting early.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu -o pipefail

function foo() {
  local sec="$1"
  echo "start foo $sec"
  sleep "$sec"
  echo "finished foo $sec"
  if ((sec == 1)); then
    return 1
  fi
}

export -f foo

echo "starting..."
printf '%s\0' 4 2 1 | xargs -t -0 -I{} -P 2 bash -c 'foo "{}" || exit 255' || echo "finished early, exit_code=$?"
echo "finished"
```

```
❯ ./tester 
starting...
bash -c 'foo "4" || exit 255' 
bash -c 'foo "2" || exit 255' 
start foo 4
start foo 2
finished foo 2
bash -c 'foo "1" || exit 255' 
start foo 1
finished foo 1
xargs: bash: exited with status 255; aborting
finished early, exit_code=124
finished

....... Last command took 3s 
❯ finished foo 4
```

The last line prints after I see the bash prompt. Interestingly, if I try to run 4 tasks (4,2,1,5), the code works as expected:

```
printf '%s\0' 4 2 1 5 | xargs -t -0 -I{} -P 2 bash -c 'foo "{}" || exit 255' || echo "finished early, exit_code=$?"
```

Is this a bug in xargs, or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:** `xargs` version: `(GNU findutils) 4.7.0` on Linux Mint 20.2

Comment: Note that `xargs -I{} bash -c '...{}...'` incurs serious security risks, no matter what kind of quoting you use around the `{}`. Consider the data item `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` -- it executes in all possible contexts (unquoted, single-quoted, double-quoted).

Comment: (As another aside that doesn't strictly address your question: I also strongly advise against using `set -e` -- its behavior varies wildly between shells and also between individual versions of the same shell, making code difficult to review for correctness; see the [exercise section of BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises))

Comment: Also, I'd strongly suggest `printf '%s\0' 4 2 1 5`. The format string gets repeated as many times as necessary to consume all arguments. Also, you want to have a final NUL -- the NUL is a terminator, not a deliminator. Just as `read` returns a nonzero exit status if there's no newline at the end (and `read -d ''` if there's no NUL at the end), behavior of xargs when you don't have a final delimiter is not well-defined.

Comment: Also, re: `function foo() {`, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you, but I tried to create a simple reproducible test that can be easily looked at by the community, without considering other aspects. Feel free to edit the example to make it simpler.

Comment: BTW, I _can't_ reproduce the stated behavior. See your code running at https://ideone.com/BbE6t0; nothing is printed after the `finished` line.

Comment: (Going back into the tangent I started earlier: As a more secure alternative to `xargs -I{} bash -c '...{}...'`, consider `xargs bash -c 'for arg; do foo "$arg" || exit 255; done' _`; it's also more efficient, because you can pass more items to each copy of bash -- tuning how many with the `xargs -n` argument -- and pay shell startup costs less frequently).

Comment: Anyhow, back to topic: Might I suggest editing your specific xargs release into the question?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your example link does not work -- it does not have `finished foo 4` line, because it prints AFTER the program terminates, which is the whole point.  Try it locally or in a docker container.

Comment: If you want a firm guarantee, `flock` is your friend. Grab a lock in the parent, start the children, release the lock in the parent, try to grab it again in the parent. When you succeed, you know the children are dead. I've probably written that up elsewhere in the knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, I'm able to reproduce OP's output ...

Of interest:

- OP mentions: *The sleep 1 task crashes, but for some reason xargs does not wait for sleep 4 to finish*
- output (OP's and mine) shows the last message on `stderr` as *xargs: bash: exited with status 255; aborting*
- according to `man xargs`:

> If any invocation of the command exits with a status of 255, xargs
> will stop immediately without reading any further input.  An error
> message is issued on stderr when this happens.

- we also see in the output: *exit_code=124* which also matches the `xargs` exit codes from the man page:

> 124    if the command exited with status 255

It appears (to me) that what really happened is:

- a command 'crashes' with a status of 255
- `xargs` sees the command crash and reports the issue (ie, the last message on `stderr`)
- `xargs` stops immediately (per documenation; counter to OP's comment *xargs does not wait*) but ...
- any already-invoked commands (`foo()` in this case) continue to run (ie, `xargs` spawned processes do not receive a kill/stop signal)
- due to `xargs` stopping we immediately find ourselves back at the command prompt
- the still-running command (`foo()`) finally completes with the output from said command now showing up in the console/terminal

Per `man xargs` it looks like `xargs` is functioning as designed.

fwiw, my `xargs` version:

```
$ xargs --version
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.8.0
```

---

Addressing OP's question/comment:

Why does `printf '%s\0' 4 2 1 5 ...` not show this same behavior?

The fact is it does show the same behavior:

```
$ ./tester
starting...
bash -c 'foo "4" || exit 255'
bash -c 'foo "2" || exit 255'
start foo 4
start foo 2
finished foo 2
bash -c 'foo "1" || exit 255'
start foo 1
finished foo 1                                     # last foo call finishes well before the script finishes
xargs: bash: exited with status 255; aborting      # xargs sees a 255 and aborts
finished foo 4                                     # even this longer foo call finishes before the script finishes
finished early, exit_code=124                      # xargs exit code = 124
finished
$                                                  # nothing shows up 'after' our script finishes
```

Notice:

- `foo 5` is not invoked
- all other `foo()` calls finish **before** the script finishes hence no output 'after' the script finishes

Net result, we have a race condition whereby all `foo()` calls just happen to complete *before* the script completes.

We can see this race condition switched if we switch the args so that the last `foo()` call sleeps for more than a couple seconds, eg, with `printf '%s\0' 4 2 5 1 ...` we see:

```
$ ./tester
starting...
bash -c 'foo "4" || exit 255'
bash -c 'foo "2" || exit 255'
start foo 4
start foo 2
finished foo 2
bash -c 'foo "5" || exit 255'
start foo 5
finished foo 4
bash -c 'foo "1" || exit 255'
start foo 1
finished foo 1
xargs: bash: exited with status 255; aborting     # xargs sees a 255 and aborts
finished early, exit_code=124                     # xargs exit code = 124
finished
$                                                 # initially nothing but command prompt but ...
```

... couple seconds later the (now orphaned) `foo 5` call completes and our console/terminal looks like:

```
... snip ...
finished early, exit_code=124
finished
$ finished foo 5
```

---

As for the question of how to get the script to *wait* until all `foo()` calls have completed, regardless of whether or not `xargs` aborts`?

Of particular interest ...

- when the `xargs` call is aborted the still-running `foo()` call is effectively orphaned and disassociated from the parent script
- adding a `wait` at the end of the script has no effect since the now-orphaned `foo()` call is not a subordinate of the main script

At this point I think this becomes a new question(s):

- How to (re)write this script so that after `xargs` aborts we *wait* for any `xargs`-spawned processes to complete?

Alternatively:

- How does a shell script *wait* on another, unrelated OS process to complete?

Comment: Thanks, but how do you explain the 4-task test as mentioned at the bottom of my post -- why does that finish all output properly?

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan same behavior applies but because the last `foo()` call is so short (`sleep 1`) we see the final `foo()` output show up in the terminal before the script 'ends'; I've updated the answer with more details ... notice where the `foo()` output lines show up in relation to the output from the aborted `xargs` ... for this whole script we're dealing with a race condition at the end ... which of 2 'parallel' processes finishes first ... the aborted `xargs` or the 'orphaned' `foo()` call ... it depends on how long the `foo()` call sleeps

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make sense -- first thread -- 4 seconds, second thread -- 2s + 1s seconds.  That means the 2nd thread should be done a whole second earlier than first, and should quit right away, but it doesn't.  To test, try setting first value to 10 instead of 4, and see that it still waits until 1st is done.

Comment: And of course the more important question is how would i do what i need to do, rather than why it doesn't work :)

Comment: using `printf '%s\0' 10 2 5 1` shows the same behavior ... `finished foo 10` prints after the script 'ends'; you can get all kinds of results by changing the length of the sleeps and the number of `-P`arallel invocations, eg, `10 2 5 1` + `-P 10` => `finished foo 2`, `finished foo 5` and `finished foo 10` all print after the script has ended (ie, after `xargs` has aborted); pay attention to where the `finished foo #` lines display in stdout wrt the `xargs` abort messages

Comment: No no, you used the wrong sequence -- try `10 2 1 5`.  The output is `xargs: bash: exited with status 255; aborting`, waiting ~5 seconds, and prints `finished foo 10`, `finished early, exit_code=124`, and `finished`, afterwards showing the prompt. This totally disproves the point that 255 causes immediate stop IMO.

Comment: on my system ... switching to `10 2 1 5` and the 3x longer `foo` calls (2/5/10) all print after I'm returned to the command prompt; again, this all comes down to a race condition ... how long it takes the `foo()` call(s) to complete vs how long it takes for the `xargs` abort to take place vs who-knows-what-other-OS-scheduling-queuing-issues-could-be-at-play-on-the-system-where-the-script-is-being-run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237536/discussion-between-yuri-astrakhan-and-markp-fuso).

Comment: did you run `printf '%s\0' 10 2 1 5 | xargs -t -0 -I{} -P 2 bash -c 'foo "{}" || exit 255' || echo "finished early, exit_code=$?"` ?  Or was your `-P` something else?  I tried it using docker bash, and got the same result